# Adding a click-event to all textboxes in wpf

Tags: wpf, inheritance, mvvm, textbox

in my applications all inputs in textboxes have to be done by a inputbox i wrote myself. so whenever a textbox is klicked, the inputbox pops up. it looks like this:

the textbox in xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Level}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding EnterLevel}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

the command in the VM:

```
private void ExecuteEnterLevel()
    {
        var dialog = new BFH.InputBox.InputBox("Level", 1, 1, 4);
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        Level = Convert.ToInt16(dialog.Input);
    }
```

so the result of the inputbox becomes the text of the inputbox. this works fine.

now my question is: can i do that for all of my textboxes that need that functionality without coding an event for every single textbox? i would like to have "myTextbox" which does it automatically.

what i tried so far:
my textbox:

```
class MyTextbox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextbox()
    {
        this.MouseDown += MyTextbox_MouseDown;
    }

    private void MyTextbox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        var dialog = new BFH.InputBox.InputBox("titel", "input");
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        tb.Text = dialog.Input;
    }
}
```

and in xaml:

```
<libraries:MyTextbox/>
```

but `MyTextbox_MouseDown` is never executet. i put `MessageBox.Show("test")` in it without any results. i am doing something wrong i guess.

Comment: not via InputBindings, but you may do it via attached properties

Comment: can you post a simple example how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not possible to define InputBindings in styles, at least in a straight forward way.  I offer to solve the issue by using AttachedProperties

lets start by defining a class for the attached property

```cs
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class EventHelper 
    {
        public static ICommand GetLeftClick(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(LeftClickProperty);
        }

        public static void SetLeftClick(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(LeftClickProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LeftClick.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftClickProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LeftClick", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnLeftClickChanged));

        private static void OnLeftClickChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement elem = d as FrameworkElement;
            ICommand command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            if (command != null)
                elem.InputBindings.Add(new MouseBinding(command, new MouseGesture(MouseAction.LeftClick)));
        }
    }
}
```

this is basically translation of mouse binding in your code done on property changed.

usage

```
<TextBox l:EventHelper.LeftClick="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

if you wish to apply to all TextBoxes then wrap the same in a generic style targeted to TextBox

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="l:EventHelper.LeftClick"
            Value="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</Style>
```

`l:` in the above refers to the name space of the above declared class eg `xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF"`

a full example

```
<StackPanel xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="l:EventHelper.LeftClick"
                    Value="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

---

**Attaching input box behavior**

class

```
class InputHelper
{
    public static bool GetIsInputBoxEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsInputBoxEnabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsInputBoxEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsInputBoxEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsInputBoxEnabled.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInputBoxEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsInputBoxEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(InputHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsInputBoxEnabled));

    private static void OnIsInputBoxEnabled(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = d as TextBox;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            tb.PreviewMouseDown += elem_MouseDown;
        else
            tb.PreviewMouseDown -= elem_MouseDown;
    }

    static void elem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        var dialog = new BFH.InputBox.InputBox(tb.GetValue(InputBoxTitleProperty), tb.GetValue(InputProperty));
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        tb.Text = dialog.Input;
    }

    public static string GetInputBoxTitle(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(InputBoxTitleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInputBoxTitle(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InputBoxTitleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InputBoxTitle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputBoxTitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InputBoxTitle", typeof(string), typeof(InputHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static string GetInput(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(InputProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInput(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(InputProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Input.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Input", typeof(string), typeof(InputHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

usage

```
<TextBox l:InputHelper.IsInputBoxEnabled="true" 
         l:InputHelper.InputBoxTitle="Title"
         l:InputHelper.Input="Input" />
```

or via styles

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="l:InputHelper.IsInputBoxEnabled"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="l:InputHelper.Title"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="l:InputHelper.Input"
            Value="Input" />
</Style>
```

using attached properties will enable you to attach this behavior to existing classes instead of inheriting from them.

---

if you are inheriting the text box class you can add two properties to the same

eg

```
class MyTextbox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextbox()
    {
        this.PreviewMouseDown += MyTextbox_MouseDown;
    }

    private void MyTextbox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        var dialog = new BFH.InputBox.InputBox(InputBoxTitle, Input);
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        tb.Text = dialog.Input;
    }

    public string InputBoxTitle { get; set; }

    public string Input { get; set; }
}
```

usage

```
<libraries:MyTextbox InputBoxTitle="Title"
                     Input="Input" />
```

Comment: sorry i don't get it. isn't that binding all my textboxes to the same command ond leftclick? what i basically need is a textbox which shows my inputbox on click, the result of the inputbox shall become the text of the textbox.

Comment: I think I overlooked the question for the sake of title. seems like you want to create a new text box with the functionality of input box. in this case you have two options, either to inherit the textbox and write the logic, or to write a generic command handler.  either of these approach may not solve your issue completely as there will be some uniqie logic with every textbox. writing a generic handler may help you minimize some repeated code without a need to inheriting the class.

Comment: i am trying to do it with inheriting, without success so far. i updated my question above for better understanding.

Comment: you may change to `PreviewMouseDown` that would give you the event, mean while I will write a sample using attached properties so you don't have to inherit the textbox.

Comment: thanks, using `PreviewMouseDown`works. this will lead me to the next point. `"titel"` and `"input"` should be strings defined in the xaml cause they are different on every textbox.

Comment: @user3815356 I had updated the answer. is there anything else I may help you with?

Comment: thank you man! they way with an attached property seems to be much more complicated than just inheriting from TextBox. it works fine that way. is there a drawback doing it with a simple custom control like that?

Comment: @el-nino, both approach are fine. attached property works best when you can not change the controls, or you want the behavior to be attachable. attached property may look little complex but it offers other benefits like binding, changed handler, coercing, validation etc. last but not the least happy coding :)